# Keep CSS comments in Vue single file components on production build?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-4

Scenario is as follows:

Vue CLI 3 project using Tailwindcss and Purgecss to remove unused classes.

"@ky-is/vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "^1.4.0"

Trying to import a vendor css file within my `<style>` block but the `/* csspurge start ignore */` and `/* csspurge end ignore */` comments are stripped out during production build.

Example:

```
<style lang="postcss">

/* csspurge start ignore */
@import 'my-vendor-css-file.css';
/* csspurge end ignore */

.my-other-styles-to-be-purged {
 ...
}

</style>
```

The issue is that my vendor file is getting purged because the webpack loader strips out the comments during a production build.

Any help on how to configure webpack to not do this in Vue CLI 3 environment? I tried looking at css-loader options but couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: do you know how i could just keep the` css` in the `.vue` file on production build for a vue library?

Answer (score 0):

Failing to figure out how to keep comments in Vue components during production build, the workaround I found was to just whitelist all the vendor classes that I wanted to keep in my postcss.config.js file:

```
const isHotReloaded = process.argv.includes('serve')

class TailwindVueExtractor {
    static extract (content) {
        const contentWithoutStyleBlocks = content.replace(/<style[^]+?<\/style>/gi, '')
        return contentWithoutStyleBlocks.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:/]+/g) || []
    }
}

const extensionsUsingCSS = [ 'vue', 'html' ]
const extensionsOfCSS = [ 'less', 'pcss', 'postcss', 'sass', 'scss', 'styl' ]

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-preset-env')({ stage: 2 }),
        require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
        !isHotReloaded && require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({
            content: [ `./@(public|src)/**/*.@(${extensionsUsingCSS.join('|')})` ],
            css: [ `./src/**/*.@(${extensionsOfCSS.join('|')})` ],
            whitelistPatterns: [
                /^vue-form-wizard/
            ],
            whitelistPatternsChildren: [
                /vue-form-wizard$/
            ],
            extractors: [
                {
                    extractor: TailwindVueExtractor,
                    extensions: extensionsUsingCSS
                }
            ]
        }),
        require('autoprefixer')()
    ]
}
```

The **whitelistPatterns** and **whitelistPatternsChildren** are the key. For more info on what each accomplishes you can check the purgecss docs [here](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss-docs/blob/master/whitelisting.md)

Not exactly what I was trying to accomplish but it works...

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but you can use important comments to tell Webpack not to strip them.
replace `/* purgecss start ignore */` with `/*! purgecss start ignore */` and it should work.